# Not able to pass arguments with spaces to python script from c#

Tags: python, c#, startprocessinfo

I am calling python script from c# using ProcessInfoStart method. As an argument it receives JSON and is input to python script.

It works fine it we pass JSON without having any spaces but if there is any space then original JSON is splitted till space and passes as argument and rest ignored

```
public static bool ExecutePythonScript(string jRequest, string fileType)
{
    string pythonExePath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PythonExe"]);
    bool bIsExecutionSuccess = true;
    try
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = pythonExePath;
        var script = @"C:Scripts\pdf-to-csv.py";

        psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{jRequest}\"";

        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var errors = "";
        var results = "";
        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
            bIsExecutionSuccess = false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        bIsExecutionSuccess = false;
    }
    return bIsExecutionSuccess;
}
```

Python script to accept arguments

```
input_params = sys.argv[1]
input_params = input_params.replace("'",'"')
data_params = json.loads(input_params)
```

Is there a way i can pass **jRequest** with spaces to python script.

Answer (score 0):

Python script **parameters** can be wrapped in **single quotes** in order to read the **whole string including spaces**.

Try wrapping the **JSON string** in **single quotes**.

Comment: Is this the way ? psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \'\"{jRequest}\"\'". That is actually not working for me, i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use double quotes around the arguments so that the entire argument with spaces was passed in to the python script.

```
Process p = new()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonPath, "queryDb.py \"" + query + "\"")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Sora Teichman\\source\\repo"
            }
        };
        p.Start();
```

Make sure to escape the double quotes with back slashes.